# How to get rid of bias in the linear discriminant function?

Tags: regression

If the linear discriminant function is:

$() = ^  + $

How to modify the feature representation of the example and the coefficient (weight) vector so that the bias is not needed?

Comment: This is a pretty common problem in early prob/stats classes. Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).